# Global minimum value using Gradient Descent for logistic regression using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, global-variables, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to calculate the global minimum values using Gradient Descent algorithm in MATLAB.
The derivated form is:
[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJkBT.png)

My Code is:

```
%Load and split the features and label 
data = load('Data.txt');
X = data(:,1:2);
y = data(:,3);

%Add a new feature
X = [ones(m,1),X];

%Define the length and initial theta value
[m,n] = size(X);
alpha = 0.01;
iteration = 400;
theta = zeros(n,1);
[theta,hist] = GradientDescent(X,y,m, alpha, theta, iteration);
J = CostFunction(X,y,theta,m);
fprintf('The cost for inital value zero is: %f\n',J);
fprintf('Minimum Gradient Descent is:\n')
fprintf('%f\n',theta)
```

My GradientDescent Functio is:

```
function [theta,hist] = GradientDescent(X,y,m,alpha, theta, iteration)
hist = zeros(m,1);
for i = 1:iteration
    z = X * theta;
    sigmoid = Sigmoid(z);
    theta = theta - sum((alpha/m) *(X' * (sigmoid - y)));
    hist(i) = CostFunction(X,y,theta,m);
end
```

Cost Function is:

```
function [J,grad] = CostFunction(X,y,theta,m)
J = 0;
z = X * theta;
hpyX = Sigmoid(z);
J = (1/m) .* ((-y' * log(hpyX)) - ((1-y)' * log(1-hpyX)));
grad = (1/m) * (X' * (hpyX - y));
end
end
```

and Sigmoid function is:

```
function sigmoid = Sigmoid(z)
sigmoid = zeros(size(z));
sigmoid = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z));
end
```

I am getting output:

```
The cost for initial value zero is: *NaN*
Minimum Gradient Descent is:
0.413048
0.413048
0.413048
```

On the other hand, when I am getting different resutl for 400 iteration in ***fminunc*** is:

```
option = optimset('GradObj','on','MaxIter',400);
[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(CostFunction(X,y,t,m)),theta,option);
fprintf('The cost function by fminunc is: %f\n',J)
fprintf('Theta is:\n')
fprintf('%f\n',theta)
```

**Output**

```
The cost function by fminunc is: 0.693147
Theta is:
-25.161343
0.206232
0.201472
```

I can't understand why I am getting different? Is there I made mistake in the **gradient descent** function? Also, I am getting NaN value for cost function, when I ma calculating Gradient Descent.

Comment: Hi, it is highly unlikely that you find the *global* minimum with a gradient descent approach unless the function has only a unique minimum. This is due to the working principle (always follow the path downhill, do not look over the next hill)

Comment: I am newbie in Machine Learning. At this situation, what I have to now

Comment: OK, well I guess that this is simple optimization rather than machine learning (but this finding won't help you^^). Your output states that `J` is `NaN`. I would guess that it is not supposed to be that. So place a *conditional breakpoint* in your functions that uses e.g. `isnan(X,'all')` and debug the code